# I'm using a repeater to dynamically add labels to an asp.net page, but the text is stacking vertically for some reason. Anyone know why this happens?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiZcs.jpg)

Code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPBM" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPBM" EnableViewState="false" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'/>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

I'm trying to add labels to a page dynamically using the above repeater, but when they are added it stacks vertically.  Anyone ever encounter this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, the DataSource and DataBind() were in a loop so it was adding one letter at a time.  Once I moved them out, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a line break after each label (br tag). Was that intended?

Remember that for each item in your data set it will write out that whole statement between the  tags.

Maybe try writing out the html manually until you get it how you like and then put it into the item template.

Comment: The break is to space labels as more are added, I'm currently trying something with the logic and I believe I may be on to something.